# Is it possible to set ZED 2i IMU ENU Frame

Tags: ros2, imu

I am trying to implement the ZED 2i IMU data into the robot_localization Extended Kalman Filter. The robot_localization package requires the IMU sensor to be in the ENU frame (0 when facing east, and pi/2 when facing north). However, the ZED 2i IMU data automatically sets the orientation to zero for the current orientation of the camera whenever you start the zed_wrapper. I was wondering how would one go about doing the conversion?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics,* Harsh Shah. Do you have a datasheet you can link for your IMU and can you please link to the code or documentation for `robot_localization` that shows it requires the IMU output in an ENU frame? My initial reaction is that you have a six-axis IMU (angular velocities and linear accelerations) but your package requires a **nine**-axis IMU (six axis plus magnetometer). If your IMU doesn't have a magnetometer then all it can ever do is to initialize to the starting/power-on pose and you *cannot* determine ENU orientation.